# Advice on number of dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to Heroku, and would like to have some idea of how I can go about guesstimating the number of dynos that might be needed for a RoR app (need to give some number to customer).

The app is already running on the free 1 dyno. Here's some basic info about the app:

- App is mainly database reads, with very little writes
- Possibly heavy DB load, with queries involving distance calculations (from lat-long, using gmaps4rails)
- From some basic testing with WAPT (eval version), it looks like a typical search request takes a min. ~1.3s, avg. ~2s, max. 4-5s
- Again from WAPT testing, up to 20 concurrent users and observing the Heroku logs, I don't seem to be seeing any requests being queued
- Other requests are largely static assets

How would I get some rough idea of the number of dynos needed, to handle X concurrent users, or how many concurrent users the single dyno can likely handle?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried actually load testing your setup? Load one dyno, see when it breaks. Fire up one more, repeat.

Comment: Yup, as I mentioned, I used this tools called WAPT to capture a user session and then simulate ramping up to 20 users (that's the max that the eval version would give me). Up to 20 users, the 1 dyno seems fine. Guess I'll have to find other ways/tools to simulate higher load.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't familiar with the tool. You can try replaying logs yourself in as many threads as you want.

Comment: Use the Blitz Add-on with heroku. It allows 250 current request for free. And it's easy to use being a Heroku add-on.

Answer (score 13):

Update: Heroku changed their dyno pricing prolicy https://www.heroku.com/pricing, so the these information might not correct anymore.

According to this article http://neilmiddleton-eu.herokuapp.com/getting-more-from-your-heroku-dynos/, if you use Unicorn, 1 dyno can handle 1 million request per day (100ms per request). So if you host all media in S3, 1 page view need 3 requests (1 html, 1 pipe-lined css, 1 pipe-lined javascript), 1 dyno can handle roughly 300.000 page view a day, or 80 page view per seconds with Unicorn.

Let's say 1 user will view 1 page in 5 seconds, and your application can manage to respond in 300ms, technically, you will have roughly 400 concurrent users with 1 dyno.

But actually our application (quite heavy), 1 dyno can only accept 1/10 of those, around 50 concurrent users.

Hope this help you!

Comment: When you say 1 dyno, are you talking about actually 1 dyno (the free dyno you get) or 1 additional dyno? With only 1 dyno, the dyno shuts down afer 1 hour of inactivity and then needs to boot on the first request.

Comment: With a proper use of new relic to check site frequently, you don't have to worry about shutdown. This example site uses only 1 dyno (free), and it lives 24 hours [Planing poker](http://poker.forexp.net)

Comment: How about Puma? Since Heroku recommends to use puma now, do you have any analysis regarding to '# of concurrent user request' on today's Heorku 1 dyno?